# OpenPyXL - Error message when opening finished excel sheet?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

i am wrting some data to an excel-sheet using OpenPyXL -looks something like this -

part of the code looks like this:

```
...
book = load_workbook (filename)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter (filename, engine='openpyxl', options={'strings_to_numbers': True})     ...
writer.book = book
pd.DataFrame (content).to_excel (writer, sheet_name=stock, header=False, index=False)
ws = writer.sheets[stock]
...
writer.save ()
writer.close ()
```

Every time when i want to open the final excel-sheet - i get an error that the sheet must be repaired - the log-file for this repairing looks like that:

[image]

When i press on yes - in the excel everything look like expected and i get this error message:

[image]

When i look in this xml-link i see this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>

-<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">

<logFileName>error183040_01.xml</logFileName>

<summary>Fehler in Datei 'C:\Users\Polzi\Documents\DEV\Python-Private\FVOut.xlsx'</summary>


-<additionalInfo>

<info>Excel hat die Überprüfung und Reparatur auf Dateiebene abgeschlossen. Einige Teile dieser Arbeitsmappe wurden repariert oder verworfen.</info>

</additionalInfo>

</recoveryLog>
```

How can i get rid of this error message when opening the excel?
Is something wrong with my handlingof the openpyxl-writer or a parameter missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it think i found the solution or at least a workaround - when i delete

```
writer.save ()
```

everything seems to be working fine (again)